# How do I make a python dictionary from a string?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, protein-database

I am collecting protein sequence ids from this website: https://www.uniprot.org/

I've written this code:

```
url = 'https://www.uniprot.org/uploadlists/'

params = {
'from': 'ID',
'to': 'UPARC',
'format': 'tab',
'query': 'P00766    P40925'

}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
data = data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as f:
   response = f.read()
   string_it = (response.decode('utf-8'))
print(string_it)
```

When I print the resulting string:

I get an output that looks like this:

```
From    To
P00766  UPI000011047C
P40925  UPI0000167B3E
```

How do I convert this to a dictionary?

Comment: can you post the contents of string_it as text rather than an image, the code is unrunable as df is not defined

Comment: I've edited the code so that it can run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, just appropriately split and use the values in the string. The code is as follows:

```
string_list = string_it.split("\n")
string_list = [i for i in string_list if i!=""]
dict_values = {}
for i in string_list[1:]:
    dict_values[i.split("\t")[0]] = i.split("\t")[1]
    
dict_values
```

The output is:

```
{'P00766': 'UPI000011047C', 'P40925': 'UPI0000167B3E'}
```

---

Code walk through:

- Initially, split the string based on new lines.
- This generally results in an empty entry. So, remove that.
- Initialize a dictionary.
- Loop through the lines, ignoring the first entry because it is just `From` and `To` .
- Split it based on `\t` the delimiter and add the values into the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your string is something like this:

```py
string_it = """
From    To
P00766  UPI000011047C
P40925  UPI0000167B3E
"""
```

You can use `splitlines()` to split all the lines. Then again using `split()` to split the single line.

```py
new_dict = {}
for line in string_it.splitlines():
  if line == "":
    continue
  new_dict[line.split()[0]] = line.split()[1]

new_dict
```